# tondev "Error: Param params (tuple) expect name at ..." when with payload param

Tags: solidity, everscale

I am using [tondev](https://github.com/tonlabs/tondev) and trying to call the function with payload param:

`tondev contract run Wallet sendTransaction --input "dest: 0x5074b87aa1ece77b28f652ccd43db00b83c20da606529d2fdf7bb0f4ce9704a3, payload: te6ccgEBAQEABgAACETLeAA="`

And got the error:

`Error: Param params (tuple) expect name at "...0f4ce9704a3, ->  payload: te..."`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems:

1. Remove the `0x`
2. Remove the spaces
3. Remove the quotes

After these changes you should have the following command which works:

```
tondev c r Wallet sendTransaction -i dest:5074b87aa1ece77b28f652ccd43db00b83c20da606529d2fdf7bb0f4ce9704a3,payload:te6ccgEBAQEABgAACETLeAA=
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out these errors:

1. 0x in address
2. Spaces.
3. Address and payload without quotes.

This is correct version:

`tondev contract run Wallet sendTransaction --input "dest:5074b87aa1ece77b28f652ccd43db00b83c20da606529d2fdf7bb0f4ce9704a3,payload:te6ccgEBAQEABgAACETLeAA="`

In bash script, with variables:

`tondev contract run Wallet sendTransaction --input "dest:$RandomAddress,payload:$payload"`